# Prepared statement with unknown data type in Node.js mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, input, types, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a prepared statement in Node.js with the `mssql` library like the one in the official documentation:

```
const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(/* [pool] */)
ps.input('param', sql.Int)
ps.prepare('select @param as value', err => {
    // ... error checks

    ps.execute({param: 12345}, (err, result) => {
        // ... error checks

        // release the connection after queries are executed
        ps.unprepare(err => {
        // ... error checks

        })
    })
})
```

In my scenario I don't know the data type for the input function. Does something like `sql.Null` or sql.Object exist? So that it is possible to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections, while using a default data type:

```
ps.input('param', sql.Null)
```

Comment: T-SQL does not have an ambiguous data type, no. The closest you have is `sql_variant` and that *really* should not be used.

Comment: SQL is a strongly typed language => the type must be known.

Comment: Have you reviewed the list of [supported data types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#data-types)?